# What is the @ symbol in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-decorators

Why in components or directives do the metadata or decorators have the `@` symbol (e.g. `@Component`, `@Directive`)?

What is the purpose of it, and when should I use it?

Comment: shortcut for annotation

Comment: You might find reading this helpful. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: You should have run across this when you read the TypeScript documentation. Or, you could google for "typescript  at-sign".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the @ (at sign) mean in the latest TypeScript (presumably v1.5) example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906505/what-does-the-at-sign-mean-in-the-latest-typescript-presumably-v1-5-exampl)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It stands for decorators. It is not TypeScript specific.

Google "javascript decorator" to learn more about it.

For example:

http://javascript.info/tutorial/decorators

https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.jzu13e5lr

For up to date information about their standard implementation and when it will finally be released (future ECMAScript versions), see this page:
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

And as @hardikModha mentioned, you can also look up the TypeScript handbook:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html